pyodbc.connect() gives an error when executing it with pytest
When executing the following code inside of my test function
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
It throws the following error:
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
The connection string of my tests is the same as in my project.
connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=database;UID=admin;PWD=pass;'
The test project also uses the same virtual environment with the same dependencies.
What happens here?
I have tried to execute it with different odbc drivers but pyodbc always returns the same error.

What's your query? I think connection_string is not the problem

question also posted on GitHub here
